# How do I create a resource on my api gateway through the aws CLI if there is no parent resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

The [documentation](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/apigateway/create-resource.html) has me really confused:

```
create-resource
--rest-api-id <value>
--parent-id <value>
--path-part <value>
[--cli-input-json | --cli-input-yaml]
[--generate-cli-skeleton <value>]
```

```
--parent-id (string)

[Required] The parent resource’s identifier.
```

The `create-resource` command takes a required parameter of `--parent-id`, but I have no clue what that's even referring to. If this is a "top-level" resource, there isn't a parent id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `parent-id` is the resource that the gateway lives on. You can find it by calling `aws apigateway get-resources --rest-api-id {your api id} --region {region}`